# when invoking a java method by method.invoke() its not returning any value instead print in the console log

Tags: java, compiler-construction, invoke, javacompiler, web-compiler

Hello please help me to find a solution for this problem, I'm creating an web compiler for java programs I have implemented the java inbuilt compiler class to compile the code and its also giving the output but it's giving output in the console and I want that output in the return object or some string variable so I can display the output in front. I'm attaching full code.

```
package online_compiler.web;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;


public class compiler {
    public static void myMethod(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
    {
        int result;
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        String program = "public class Main{" + " public static void main (String [] args){"
            + " System.out.println (\"Hello, World\");"
            + " }" + "}";
        
        JavaSourceFromString jsfs = new JavaSourceFromString("Main", program);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjects = Arrays.asList( jsfs);
        java.util.List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
        options.add("-d");
        options.add("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12.0.2\\bin");
        options.add( "-classpath");
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader =
                (URLClassLoader)Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for (URL url : urlClassLoader.getURLs()) {
           sb.append(url.getFile()).append(java.io.File.pathSeparator);
       }
       sb.append("C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Java\\\\jdk-12.0.2\\\\bin");
       options.add(sb.toString());

       StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
       boolean success = compiler.getTask( output, null, null, options, null, fileObjects).call(); 
       if(success) {
           name = output.toString();
           System.out.print(output);
           java.io.File root = new java.io.File("C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Java\\\\jdk-12.0.2\\\\bin");
           URLClassLoader classLoader;
        try {   
            classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { root.toURI().toURL() });
                Object obj = null;
               Class<?> cls = Class.forName("Main", true, classLoader);
               try {
                obj = cls.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                Method m = cls.getMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
                Object[] _args = new Object[] { new String[0] };
                Object retobj =  m.invoke(obj, _args);
                System.out.println(retobj);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

           //logger.info( LOG_PREFIX + "Class has been successfully compiled");
       } else {
           //throw new Exception( "Compilation failed :" + output);
       }
        
    }
    
    static Iterable<JavaSourceFromString> getJavaSourceFromString(String code) {
        final JavaSourceFromString jsfs;
        jsfs = new JavaSourceFromString("code", code);
        return new Iterable<JavaSourceFromString>() {
          public Iterator<JavaSourceFromString> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<JavaSourceFromString>() {
              boolean isNext = true;

              public boolean hasNext() {
                return isNext;
              }

              public JavaSourceFromString next() {
                if (!isNext)
                  throw new NoSuchElementException();
                isNext = false;
                return jsfs;
              }

              public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
              }
            };
          }
        };
      }
}
class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
      final String code;

      JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
        super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.', '/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
        this.code = code;
      }
      
      public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
            return code;
          }
}
```

The main driver code is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un8ET.png)

[output in the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTdIn.png)

I have tried many things searching on internet but nothing worked. I want that output in an object or a string variable so I can use that output or that string to front end.

Comment: “The output” meaning what? What’s printed to the console in the **called** code?

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: Output means the output of the code which is passed in string in this case I'm printing hello world so it gets printed in a log but I want it in a return string or an object which I have assigned it.

Answer (score 3):

The method you call is static **void** main. It doesn't return any value.
If you create a method that actually returns something, it should work better

Comment: You can check this online compiler on the W3 school code editor if I'm writing hello world in the main method it still gives output on the web so In the backend, they are returning the output value to an object or a string variable from the main method

Comment: @RajGandhi that simply means that this web application redirects the output to the web page. It does not mean that the method returns something. You should notice that the code you’re compiling contains `System.out.println("Hello, World");`, not `return "Hello, World";`